# How get Cells's value and check before open excel file use VBA in outlook

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I tried to search value of cell from outlook script and check whether Does it exist in excel file, if yes, open excel file, else do nothing. I can open file and search where is that value in range. But my problem is I don't know how to search that value in range and get it's position without open excel file.

**EDIT 1:**
Here is my detail issue: EX:
I have a phone number at column "Phone Number". I would like to find where Column of "Phone Number" (because sometime it will change to another column). After I find position of column, I would like to search whether number "123876" is existed in that column (until this time excel file still close). Now, if number "123876" is existed, open that excel file, else do nothing.
[image]

Here is my code to search if file open

```
Sub test()
    Dim objExcel As Object
    Dim WB As Object
    Dim WS As Object
    'Open excel file
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objExcel.Visible = True
    Set WB = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\Book1.xlsm")
    WB.Activate
    Set WS = WB.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    'Search position of column "Phone Number"
    Phone_Number_Col = Chr(WS.Range("A:Z").Find("Phone Number", LookIn:=xlValues).Column + 64) 'It will return 5 and change to "E" for this column
    'Search whether does my number is exist in this file
    Dim range_1 As Range
    Set Found_Nprod = WS.Range(Phone_Number_Col & ":" & Phone_Number_Col).Find("123876", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not Found_Nprod Is Nothing Then 'found my number
        MsgBox ("This value is existed")
    Else ' not find my number
        MsgBox ("This value is not existed in this file")
    End If
End Sub
```

Above code just can find when excel file is opened. But my problem is how to find like that without open file, It just open file when that file have my number "123876"

**EDIT 2:**

I found a peace of code which can get value of cell without open. It's run ok But I don't know how to use find function with it.
This is my function I found

```
Sub ReadClosed()
'
' Credit this To Bob Umlas
'
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strInfoCell As String

strPath = "D:\"
strFile = "Book1.xlsm"
i = 3
strInfoCell = "'" & strPath & "[" & strFile & "]Sheet1'!R" & i & "C1"
MsgBox "In Cell A1 = " & ExecuteExcel4Macro(strInfoCell), vbInformation, strFile
```

Comment: show your code and give more details about you issue

Comment: What do you mean "without open excel file"?  Do you just mean "without having the Excel file displayed to the user"?  Or do you also need to exclude solutions which open the file without displaying it (e.g. ADODB)?

Comment: I edited my question which more detail, please give me some your ideas and the way to solve to solve my problem

Comment: But why do you need to do this without opening the file?

Comment: Because if this number is exist in file, I had to ask user whether they would like to modified it, if they actually want to modified it, I had to open file for them, else sometime they run macro missing and they don't want to open file, I shouldn't open file

Comment: Why don't you open the file and check if the number is there. If it is, ask whether they want to modify it.  If it isn't, close the file without even bothering to ask.

Comment: Note:  The most recent bit of code you added into your question will be fairly slow - it is effectively opening/closing the file for every cell that you are trying to look at.  It will be much more efficient to open the file once, look at all the cells you need to, then close the file.

Comment: Hello YowE3K, Yes, I'm used to do like that, Open excel file, ask user whether they would like to modified it, if yes, continue, else close file. But there is one thing make me uncomfortable, when user run macro, it open and display excel file first, Now in front of my eyes is excel file, there have a msgbox in outlook, I had to back to choose outlook cho check msgbox, and it make me uncomfortable

Comment: That is a reason I would like to run msgbox to ask first and then open excel file if user would like to modified it. However, I wonder if is there any way when run macro, it still open excel file but it display msbox to ask first, and if user choose yes it will display excel file

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is how I can help you with - this is a code, that I am using, and it gives you the row of the wanted string, if you give it in which column to search. If it is not the wanted string, it returns -1. If you want the second repetitable of the string, you should give in the optional parameter `l_more_values_found` a value of `2`. If your string is `Phone` and in the sheet it is `Phones`, you should set `look_for_part` as `True`. Prety much this is how it works. Lets imagine you have this:

[image]

If you run the MyTest Sub, you would get 4 as a result. 4 is the phone number 155, which is given as a parameter to `l_locate_value_row`. In your case, you can check once you know the column that it has to search, whether it returns `-1`.

Here comes the code:

```
Public Function l_locate_value_row(target As String, ByRef target_sheet As Worksheet, _
                                   Optional l_col As Long = 2, _
                                   Optional l_more_values_found As Long = 1, _
                                   Optional b_look_for_part = False) As Long

    Dim l_values_found  As Long
    Dim r_local_range   As Range
    Dim my_cell         As Range

    l_values_found = l_more_values_found

    Set r_local_range = Nothing
    target_sheet.Activate
    Set r_local_range = target_sheet.Range(target_sheet.Cells(1, l_col), target_sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, l_col))

    For Each my_cell In r_local_range

        'The b_look_for_part is for the vertriebscase
        If b_look_for_part Then
            If target = Left(my_cell, Len(target)) Then
                If l_values_found = 1 Then
                    l_locate_value_row = my_cell.Row
                    Exit Function
                Else
                    l_values_found = l_values_found - 1
                End If
            End If
        Else
            If target = Trim(my_cell) Then
                If l_values_found = 1 Then
                    l_locate_value_row = my_cell.Row
                    Exit Function
                Else
                    l_values_found = l_values_found - 1
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next my_cell

    l_locate_value_row = -1

End Function

Public Sub MyTest()

    Dim l_col As Long

    l_col = l_locate_value_row("155", ActiveSheet, 3, 1, False)

    Debug.Print l_col

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Vityata, Thank for your quickly help. But I see in your source code, you use input is activesheet. But when I code VBA in outlook I just have a link of my file, EX "D:\Book1.xlsm". How can I get activesheet and put it to your function

Comment: Well, I used activesheet, because I did not know the name of your sheet. Usually there should be the Excel VBA name there. Concerning the reference of Excel from another application - here is something good - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821081.aspx

Comment: It's look great, but It's seem to be not solve my problem, My problem is search special value in closed excel file from outlook. Do you have any idea else. I find peace of code which can get value of cell without open file, but I don't know how to use find function of vba with it. Please see in my Edit 2 , I was add this peace of function

Comment: Well, it solves the part of the problem, saying that `After I find position of column, I would like to search whether number "123876" is existed in that column (until this time excel file still close).`

Comment: I read your link again, But it seem to be mention about example to handle with word object when we open it. I still cannot find the way how to search my value in that file which is closing :( . Could you please show me more detail

Answer (score 0):

An ADODB Query is ideal for retrieving data from a closed workbook.

### Phone Numbers

[image]

### Test

[image]

### Code

```
Function hasPhoneNumber(FilePath As String, PhoneNumber As Variant) As Boolean
    Const adOpenStatic = 3, adLockOptimistic = 3, adCmdText = 1
    Dim conn As Object, rs As Object

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
              "Data Source=" & FilePath & _
              ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"

    rs.Open "SELECT (Count([Phone Number]) > 0) AS hasPhoneNumber FROM [Sheet1$]" & _
          " WHERE Cstr([Phone Number])='" & PhoneNumber & "';", conn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

    hasPhoneNumber = CBool(rs!hasPhoneNumber)

    On Error Resume Next
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: I tried your function but it get run-time error:"No value given for one or more requiremed paramethers". And when I debug I highlight this line "    rs.Open "SELECT (Count([Phone Number]) > 0) AS hasPhoneNumber FROM [Sheet1$]" & _
          " WHERE Cstr([Phone Number])='" & PhoneNumber & "';", conn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText" . Please tell me what problem with it.

Comment: @Bruce Chances are that the field name isn't correct: `[Phone Number]`